# How to Disable loop: true for small screen size

Tags: javascript

I discovered owl carousel crashing on iphone when sliding images, and setting to `loop: off` fixed the issue.

Can you help me with this js - what do I need to add/change so that that `loop: off` applies for screen sizes < 768px and `loop: true` for all others?

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.my-carousel').owlCarousel({
        items: 1, 
        loop: true, 
        center:true, 
        margin:10, 
        URLhashListener:true,
        autoplayHoverPause:true,
        startPosition: 'URLHash',
        autoplayHoverPause: false,
        items: 1, 
        navText : ["<p><small>Prev</small> and <small>Next</small></p>"],
        responsive:{
          0:{
            items:1
          },
          600:{
            items:1
          },
          1000:{
            items:1
          }
    }   
        });
    })`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried set loop false on responsive?

And if you want do specific width use the width on responsive too, then 0, 600, 1000 in responsive behavior more like `@media only screen and (min-width : ...)`:

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.my-carousel').owlCarousel({
        items: 1, 
        //loop: true, 
        center:true, 
        margin:10, 
        URLhashListener:true,
        autoplayHoverPause:true,
        startPosition: 'URLHash',
        autoplayHoverPause: false,
        items: 1, 
        navText : ["<p><small>Prev</small> and <small>Next</small></p>"],
        responsive:{
          0:{
            items:1,
            loop: false
          },
          768:{
            items:1,
            loop: false
          },
          1000:{
            items:1,
            loop: true
          }
    }   
        });
    })`
```

Comment: Do you mean setting it in CSS using @media?

Comment: no you dont need to set CSS, as far i know the object responsive on owlCarousel will do that for you when u create object

if you declare 0, 768 and 1000 
it mean  0-767 will execute parameter on object 0,
768-999 will execute parameter on object 768
if it more than 1000 then it execute parameter on object 1000